# Can I use a wonderfl effect in my project?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, effects

[Wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net) is a library of flash effects. Their system is entirely built upon the concept that any code can be viewed and edited in a browser, and any code can be 'forked' and modified further. Since the entire system is so 'open-source' (see their [legal page](http://wonderfl.net/terms#terms_pp)), can I use one of these effects in my projects? even for commercial usage such as a web app or website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer, but the way I understand sections 5 and 6 of the Terms of Use page, anyone singing up with Wonderfl pretty much lets go of all copyrights for anything he/she submits to the site.  I would think that's a go-ahead.

**edit:**

Having read their licensing FAQ as well:  It's your responsibility to find out the licensing terms for any of the code you want to use.  Moreover, if you fork the code, you automatically accept the same license terms for your own forked piece of code.  Each piece of code might be distributed under a different license, so you should always make sure.  If you can contact the author directly, it might be a good idea to just ask.

P.S. Just in case there is any misunderstanding: Wonderfl is **not** just a library of effects.  It is a community site much like this one, where ActionScript programmers may create programs, show and distribute them to others and ask for advice.  This has other implications if, for example, you want advice on a project you are working on for your company - you should always be very certain you are actually allowed to share any code you post on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read their FAQ on licensing: http://wonderfl.net/help#help_license